# Strange Jetpack Compose Modifier Chaining Effect on Clickable Lambda

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a parent modifier. It will be the base modifier for many Card composeables. For each Card, I used "then" function to chain a clickable lambda which would start the corresponding activity. However, one Card is not clickable yet but it became clickable with parent modifier. It will apply the lambda from the first Card. I tried to apply a empty lambda, but it doesn't help. Why?

```
//parent modifier
val modifierCard = Modifier
                .height(140.dp)
                .width(140.dp)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)

//1st Card
Card(modifier = modifierCard.then(Modifier.clickable {context.startActivity(Intent(context, VehicleInfoActivity3::class.java))}),
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
                    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 12.dp),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp)
                )
                {...}

//2nd Card
Card(modifier = modifierCard.then(Modifier.clickable {context.startActivity(Intent(context, ReceivePortalActivity2::class.java))}),
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
                    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 12.dp),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp)
                )
                {...}

//3rd Card should not be clickable but it will behave like 1st Card's  clickable and start VehicleInfoActivity3
Card(modifier = modifierCard,
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
                    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 12.dp),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp)
                )
                {...}
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work. Still, VehicleInfoActivity3 was started as before.

```
//3rd Card
Card(modifier = modifierCard.then(Modifier.clickable { /*empty lamda*/ }),
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
                    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 12.dp),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp)
                )
                {...}
```

The following will behave no clickable at first. However, if I jump to other Activities and go back. It became clickable again! It will always start VehicleInfoActivity3 as before. Very strange...

```
//3rd Card
Card(modifier = Modifier
                    .height(140.dp)
                    .width(140.dp)
                    .padding(10.dp),
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
                    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 12.dp),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp)
                )
                {...}
```

[Edit]
I found the problem. There is nothing wrong with Modifier chaining. My app is based on XML UI and I'm trying to rewrite it to compose. I got 2 identical looking MainActivities (one XML, one Compose), and those legacy Activities will jump back to XML MainActivity, not the compose MainActivity. I should have removed it from the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: ```Modifier``` order does matter a lot. so when you make ```Modifier``` chain keep into mind and make necessary changes

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to reproduce your issue with the following code:

```kotlin
Column {
    val cardModifier = Modifier
        .height(64.dp)
        .width(64.dp)
        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)

    Card(
        modifier = cardModifier.then(
            Modifier.clickable { Log.i("Preview", "Card 1 clicked") }
        )
    ) {
        Text(text = "Card 1")
    }

    Card(
        modifier = cardModifier.then(
            Modifier.clickable { Log.i("Preview", "Card 2 clicked") }
        )
    ) {
        Text(text = "Card 2")
    }

    Card(
        modifier = cardModifier
    ) {
        Text(text = "Card 3")
    }
}
```

There is never a log from the Card 1 or even Card 2 after clicking Card 3:

```
 I  Card 1 clicked // after clicking Card 1
 I  Card 2 clicked // after clicking Card 2
    <NO LOG>       // after clicking Card 3
```

If this is representative example for your case then I would suggest you to not use `then` modifier and simply apply the `clickable` modifier directly as from the example it doesn't seem necessary to use `then`:

```kotlin
modifier = cardModifier.clickable { Log.i("Preview", "Card 1 clicked") }
```

Otherwise it seems like the question is lacking more details as in isolation the issue doesn't seem to be reproducible.

Comment: Thank you. It was my fault. I edited the post. There is nothing wrong with chaining modifiers.